# How to write a query to fetch an xml file from url and make a sql table in an existing DB

Tags: python, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

BSD

hi can you please help me to find a way to write an sql query to fetch an xml file from a url
and make an SQL table from it?

this is what i started doing:

```
SET TEXTSIZE -1;

DECLARE @Plant TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, url NVARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @Plant (url) VALUES
('https://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml'),   

SELECT @Plant
    
DECLARE @hdoc int
    
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @plant
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/CATALOG/PLANT' , 2)
WITH(
    CarInfo INT,
    Price INT,
    Type VARCHAR(100)
    )
    
    
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc
```

btw:

if possible in python also (i assume that the answer is positive), please send an example.

thanks!

Comment: I would suggest to make a call to the URL in Python, get the XML, pass it to a stored procedure in SQL Server, where it will be shredded via XQuery and inserted into a DB table.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from SQL Server 2005 onwards, it is better to use XQuery language, based on the w3c standards, while dealing with the XML data type.
Microsoft proprietary `OPENXML` and its companions `sp_xml_preparedocument` and `sp_xml_removedocument` are kept just for backward compatibility with the obsolete SQL Server 2000. Their use is diminished just to very few fringe cases.

Here is how to shred the XML from the 'https://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml' URL correctly by using XQuery methods `.nodes()` and `.value()`.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CATALOG>
    <PLANT>
        <COMMON>Bloodroot</COMMON>
        <BOTANICAL>Sanguinaria canadensis</BOTANICAL>
        <ZONE>4</ZONE>
        <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
        <PRICE>$2.44</PRICE>
        <AVAILABILITY>031599</AVAILABILITY>
    </PLANT>
    <PLANT>
        <COMMON>Columbine</COMMON>
        <BOTANICAL>Aquilegia canadensis</BOTANICAL>
        <ZONE>3</ZONE>
        <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
        <PRICE>$9.37</PRICE>
        <AVAILABILITY>030699</AVAILABILITY>
    </PLANT>
</CATALOG>';

SELECT c.value('(COMMON/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS [Common]
    , c.value('(BOTANICAL/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS [Botanical]
    , c.value('(ZONE/text())[1]', 'INT') AS [Zone]
    , c.value('(LIGHT/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS [Light]
    , c.value('(PRICE/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS [Price]
    , c.value('(AVAILABILITY/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS [Availability]
FROM @xml.nodes('/CATALOG/PLANT') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+-----------+------------------------+------+--------------+-------+--------------+
|  Common   |       Botanical        | Zone |    Light     | Price | Availability |
+-----------+------------------------+------+--------------+-------+--------------+
| Bloodroot | Sanguinaria canadensis |    4 | Mostly Shady | $2.44 |       031599 |
| Columbine | Aquilegia canadensis   |    3 | Mostly Shady | $9.37 |       030699 |
+-----------+------------------------+------+--------------+-------+--------------+
```